# Combined network- / webshare: file ownership and permissions

Tags: apache, permissions, afp

I'm using a combination of pyd.io and netatalk to have my remote storage available at home and from anywhere. So far (reading) everything works fine, but now — while trying to upload something for the first time — I have a problem that causes me a headache.

The directory `/mnt/data` is shared via `afpd` (netatalk) to as normal user `pi` (yes, I started with a Raspberry). Thus, file ownership is `pi:pi`, permissions `755`. Works great: I can read and write locally and from a mac via netatalk.

The same directory is shared via pyd.io via apache2. Reading works perfectly, however, writing does not, as apache runs under user `www-data:www-data`. If I chmod to `777`for test purposes, new files are created under `www-data:www-data` ownership (of course). But, they are then not writable for user `pi` via netatalk.

I really don't know how to solve this issue, since combining the two (running apache under pi or similar) seems to be very insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following steps:

1. Create new group (in my case `shared-data`)
2. Add `www-data`and `pi` to the group
3. Change permissions for the shared folder to `664`
4. Make permissions for new folders the same `chflags g+s -R /path`
5. Make permissions for new files the same with `setacl`
6. Make pyd.io create new files and folders with `664`
7. Edit netatalk share(s) in `/usr/local/etc/afp.conf`: Add `file perm = 0664`and `directory perm = 0664`
8. Restart apache and netatalk